# A question in proof of wolstenholme theorem which I am unable to understand and I can't comment due to less reputation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In my last problem which was wolstenholme theorem ( I didn't knewit was a theorem)  I was given links where wolstenholme theorem was proved. 2-3 answers contained these arguments which I cannot understand and I cannot comment author of answers to comment as I have reputation less than 50 . So, can someone please answer my question in proof of the above theorem posted on MSE.

I am adding it's images. [image]

[image]

Link of same answer - [If for a prime p $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots + \frac{1}{p-1}=\frac{a}{b}$ then show that p divides a. Moreover if $p>3$ then $p^2$ divides a.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318510/if-for-a-prime-p-1-frac12-frac13-ldots-frac1p-1-fracab)

> My question is what is the explanation for writing $\sum_{n=1}^{p'} ( ( n) p-n)^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{p'} ((n) -n) $ .
>
> Can someone please explain?  I shall be really thankful. Please understand I can't comment due to less than 50 reputation!!

Comment: To understand this you need to know about the fact that each element of $Z_{p}$ has a multiplicative inverse. In other words for $a$ in $Z_{p}$ there there exist a $b$ in $Z_{p}$ such that $ab\equiv 1 (\mod p)$ so $a^{2}\equiv b^{-2} (\mod p)$

Comment: I'm giving you an up-vote to help with your reputation problem.

Comment: @Old Peter Thank you very much . It's very kind of you

Comment: I forget mentioning in $Z_{p}$ other than 0 element in $Z_{p}$ so take that also I forget mentioning that $p$ is prime so take that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the proof you seem to be puzzled by seems to be the following. (Ask if I've misunderstood your concerns.)

The expression $n(p-n)$ has been replaced by $n(-n)$.

This is a valid replacement since we are working modulo $p$ and  $p-n$ is the same as $-n$ modulo $p$.